# azure: database 'master' on server 'xyz' is not available. Please retry the connection later

Tags: azure-sql-database

Everything was working then suddenly I received this error. Any idea please?

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to xyz.database.windows.net.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Database 'master' on server 'xyz.database.windows.net' is not currently available.  Please retry the connection later.  If the problem persists, contact customer support, and provide them the session tracing ID of '{B2EA917D-77DB-4F95-9B30-1CDFBFECB8AA}'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 40613)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=40613&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Comment: What exactly where you doing when you got the error?

Comment: it is back after 2-hour down time. no idea why.

Comment: Might be best to speak to azure support. There could be additional issues with the service itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a significant outage today on Azure that took down most databases. They had a DNS issue across the data centers so the network requests couldn't find the servers. While most databases came back by about 6 am Pacific Time, those in the US Central region took even longer.  More information is posted at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/history/